# Spring mvc restful service and client

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Hi Friends this my service code in the server side,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/pack/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json", produces = "application/json")
 public @ResponseBody String getPackByID(@PathVariable("id") int packageID) {

        System.out.println("In RESTful Service menthod ****************************");
        Vspackages vspackages = Vspackages.findVspackages(Integer.valueOf(packageID));
        return vspackages.customToJson();
 }
```

its working, returns json object when the URI called (http://thevenueplanner.com/pack/480)

I wrote Java client to access return JSON object from URI

Client code here

String BASE_URI = "http://thevenueplanner.com/";

```
public void givenConsumingJson_whenReadingTheFoo_thenCorrect() {
    String URI = BASE_URI + "pack/{id}";

    JSONArray arr = null;

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);             

    ResponseEntity<JSONObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(URI, HttpMethod.GET, entity, JSONObject.class, "480");                


    JSONObject resource = restTemplate.getForObject(URI, JSONObject.class, "480");

    System.out.println("Response: "+response.toString());

    System.out.println("resource: "+resource.toString());

}
private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getMessageConverters() {


     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();                               

     mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
     mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);


     MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
     messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);               

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(messageConverter);
    return converters;

}
```

The success message is:

> Response: <200 OK,{},{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[5189], Date=[Tue, 03 Jun 2014 08:54:50 GMT]}>
>   resource: {}

it wont give JSON object, but it tells its content length in success message,

How to get JSON object from the URI to Client

Comment: What does the client print if you call `response.getBody()`?

Comment: I tried your code as is and it worked just fine

Comment: as like before resource: {}

Comment: Like I said, your code ran just fine on my machine and returned the desired results

Comment: Is response.getBody() returns JSON object ? as like http://thevenueplanner.com/pack/480

Comment: Oh! is it possible send ur modified code

Comment: I did not modify anything! Your codes works as is for (it prints the various json fields)

Comment: Is it any security issue, i have microsoft security essential and McAfee antivirus in my system

Comment: Same output run after disabling firewall and antivirus, I am wondering its working in your side !!!

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just ran it and it worked